# Synchronize two C++ processes using a shared library

Tags: c++, synchronization, shared-libraries

I am developing a C ++ class (MyClass.cpp) that I will compile as a dynamic shared library (MyClass.so).

This shared library will be used by two different applications running on the same Linux machine.

They are two different applications. It is not a multithreaded application, nor can it be.

In this class there is a MyClass::WriteHardware method that must be executed with mutual exclusion, so
it is impossible for the two applications to run it at the same time.

What is the correct and simplest way to achieve this synchronization between two different processes,
considering that the MyClass.so library is common to both?

Would a mutex work in this case, since it is not a multithreaded application?

Comment: Which platform/OS? The concept of a "process" is not defined in the C++ standard, so it depends on the platform how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Make your `MyClass::WriteHardware` to write a "batch" file with the apps requiring this function and in proper order.

Once a job is done, remove it from the file.

The function inspects the file to see if it can do its job or must wait for other app to finish.

To prevent several apps writting to this file at once, you may use another "lock" file. Its existencd means "someone is writting to the batch file"

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using hardware locks. For example inside your MyClass::WriteHardware use another hardware object (i.e. a simple file) as a monitor for your locks. So MyClass::WriteHardware must first check if that your monitor file can be acquired with a write access, and then do its stuff while still holding the lock for that monitor file, and then release it once done with its main stuff.